# Checking if a Minecraft server is Online in Java?

Tags: java, status, minecraft

How would I go about doing this? I want to be able to check if a Minecraft server is online. The easiest method would be to check for an open port on 25565, but I don't know how to do this in Java, and anything I've read doesn't make sense to me. I have read about trying to create a 'server' on the remote domain and port, but that doesn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do raw socket programming in java like any other language. Something like this should do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
        IOException {
    boolean open = true;
    Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
    try {
        socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 25565));
        socket.close();
    } catch (ConnectException e) {
        open = false;
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    System.out.println(open);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a client that connects to the server port (search for java client using your favorite search engine)

If you want to be more thorough, use tcpdump (or something similar) to spy on the protocol between client and server (when you start Minecraft on your system) and emulate that in your client.

BTW, a search of 'minecraft server protocol' returned : http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Classic_server_protocol